# Mongoose fails to update existing document when a field is required

Tags: mongoose, meanjs

I used MEANjs to create application and added CRUD module using yo generator. Also I registered two users in the application. After that with 'user 1' I created some records. Now I need to allow 'user 2' to update the records of 'user 1'. By default this will not be allowed but I need to override that logic and allow every user that is with role 'user' to edit every existing record even those that are not created by him. I was not able to find how this can be done. Can anyone share some insights?

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't seem you want every user to have the the "admin" role (which grants total control), you will need to edit the policies file in your CRUD module.

Using the Articles module has an example:

If you go to `/modules/articles/server/policies/articles.server.policy.js`, you will need to update the permissions for the role "user":

```
, {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get']
    }]
  },
```

To allow any user to edit the article, add the "put" permission to the array:

```
, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get', 'put']
}
```

Other possible solution would be to create an array of ObjectIds in the Article model schema (located in `/modules/articles/server/models/article.server.model.js`) which will store all the ids of the users that are allowed to edit the article. Something like this:

```
allowedUsers: [{ type : ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

However in this way you will need to add more logic to the `isAllowed` middleware defined in the policies file, so that everytime someone updates the article, you will check if article.allowedUsers array contains the id of the user that made the request (`req.user` id).

Comment: Thank you for the input! I already tried extending the "permissions" attribute in the *.policy.js file and I was surprised that it did not do the job. Comparing the ids of the users seems like another workaround but it did not work as well. The issue is that calling the save() of any instance of the database shema returns error 400 with message that any fields marked as required are empty even thou they are filled and passed correctly to the db. Can this be result of ongoing updates of the shema and creating files along the way?

Comment: That seems weird, you should check your model schema. Also you should take a look at which fields you are saving to the database in the controller... maybe you're missing a property.

Comment: after many attempts I decided to download the latest version of MEANJS and just add the modules I already created to the updated skeleton. This worked as a charm. Now I can control the access to the URIs through the *.policy file as designed. I am not sure what went wrong with the version I had. Anyways...starting fresh helped this time :). Thanks for the input. I still learned the trick with the IDs

Comment: @PavelPavlov that's nice to hear :)